# Change Placeholder Shape

Tags: python, python-pptx

Can we change a placeholder shape from normal rectangle to rounded rectangle ?

I tried below code:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE

prs = Presentation(path)
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[4]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)

placeholder = slide.placeholders[1]
placeholder.auto_shape_type = MSO_SHAPE.ROUNDED_RECTANGLE ## error is coming on this line
```

But this is giving error:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Also, I cant find anything in documentation. Can this be done via `python` ?

Comment: What is the error you get?